# Why do Selene's eyes change colors in some images?

Tags: underworld

There is some images of [Selene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selene_%28Underworld%29) with brown eyes and others with electric blue eyes. I saw those movies long ago and I didn't remember nor find any explanation anywhere.

[image: Selene Brown eyes]
[image: Selene Electric blue eyes]

Why this change?

Comment: I don't remember there being an in-world explination of eye-color changing in vampires.  This is probably a continuity issue.

Comment: the first shot looks like a promotional poster, while the second looks like it is a still from the movie - could explain the variation - don't think I remember seeing eye-colour changing in the movies at all

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I thought the change of eye colour was a sign of the vampire nature manifesting itself, similar to a vampire's incisors getting longer. It's not a continuity error, because there's a scene where she's kissing the love interest and her eyes briefly pulse into blue -- a very nice effect.

Comment: Did I say kissing? I looked up a clip, and they're doing much more than kissing when her eyes change colour.

Answer (score 4):

Her eyes change color according to her mood. As she gets angry her eyes turn blue. When she has a mellow attitude or isn't annoyed they're brown.

Answer (score 0):

Her eyes change color according to her mood. Most of the time, they're brown when she's on her normal mood, but when she's pissed off, or like when she made love with Michael, her eyes turned into electric blue.

Answer (score 0):

Selene eyes turns blue because she's in attack mode when turned white at the end of *Underworld: Evolution* because she drank Michael Corvinus' blood and became hybridized.

Answer (score -1):

When a vampire's eyes change colour it's when their vampire nature is coming to the forefront. Just like the werewolves, they look human in order to blend in with the humans and go unseen, and also like the Lycans when they are in fight-mode or they are in need of their heightened senses, they shift to "vampire" which is when the eyes become almost luminescent and their incisors lengthen.

For the vampires there is 2 differences from their werewolf cousins; **1)** Obviously they don't shape shift into any creature (hybrids excluded) and **2)** their vampire traits become apparent when they are aroused. As in vampire lore blood and sex have always been closely associated.

The way they showed her eyes changing in some scenes from each of the movies was in my opinion very well done and so cool. Now my eyes change colour all the time but how cool would it be to have them change like hers?